# Установить psycopg2 на Synology

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, synology

Необходимо установить psycopg2 на Synology сервер.
Python установил через `центр пакетов` версии 3.7.7, потому что нужны f-строки.
К сожалению не очень хорошо знаком с Synology и не могу разобраться в чем причина ошибки
`Error: pg_config executable not found`.
PostgreSQL установлен, работает.
В чем может быть причина ошибки?

Comment: Если правильно понимаю, это разновидность Debian? Попробуйте установить `libpq-dev` Или `libpq-devel` для Сentos/etc

Comment: Вот вроде ответ на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037133/3442069)